# Cannot get object property from another file in PHP

Tags: php

I want to make a query to MySQL and if the query is done but if there is no result, I want to set "login_status" object property to false instead of NULL.

I have all files connected in one main file "load.php" so there is no problems with including files.

My query is defined in User.php file which containes User class with method login().

Another file is login.view.php which is html template for login functionality, but I receive message that variable $user (isntance of User) is not defined and that property login_status isn't also defined.

Here's the code from User.php:

```
class User extends Query {
    public $login_status;
    
    public function login(){
        $email = $_POST['login_email'];
        $pass = $_POST['login_pass'];
    
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM tqyr_users 
                WHERE user_email = ? 
                AND user_pass = ?;";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute([$email, $pass]);
        $is_user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
        if(is_object($is_user)){
            $_SESSION['logged'] = $is_user;
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $this->login_status = false;
            header('Location: login.php');
        }
    }.........
```

And here's the code from login.view.php:

```
    <?php if($user->login_status == false): ?>
    <p class="px-4 py-4 bg-danger text-white text-start mb-4 login-alert">Wrong email or password, please try again.</p>
 

     <?php endif; ?>
```

Once again, I have all files connected and I have defined $user instance

Comment: The problem I think is that the $user variable is not passed to the view properly. Can you share the code passing the $user variable to the view?

Comment: @Chandana login view is attached to login.php (Controller): here it si

<?php

require_once 'load.php';

isLoggedReverse();

if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
 $user->login();
}

view('login', 'Login to AdBooks account');

Comment: Have you verified that fetch isn't returning an object?

Comment: @Phaelaxz yes, it returns an object, I use that object globally to display user info and so on, but only when I want to pass login_status or change_status (when updating user) I cannot use it because of the same problem

Comment: what I'm trying to say is, you're only setting login_status if your fetched result isn't an object. I don't remember for certain, but would fetch still return an object even in an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

If 'else' is executed, it will force a new connection and consequently you will lose the variable state.

I suggest you change the responsibility of $_SESSION and header of this class.

You can return true or false in login function.